# Switching from App Engine Flex to Standard

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I created an App Engine Flex NodeJS app, not realizing that there is no free tier.  So I decided to switch to App Engine standard.  I updated my `app.yaml`, deployed, and everything seems to be working.  However, I deployed this a couple hours ago, and I still have 2 compute engine instances running.  Is there something I need to do to shut those down, or did I just not wait long enough?  I don't want them running at all because I don't want to pay for them, especially since the standard app doesn't use compute engine at all.

I tried going to the Compute Engine tab in GCP to see if I could do anything there, but all I get is a "Create instance" button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the Versions page on the Google Cloud Console and make sure that the old version is deleted and that traffic is going to the new version. It may be a good idea to use a new version for the standard env.

Then on the Instances page check if the respective instances are running and shut them down if so.

Comment: That did it! Thanks a lot!